# How can I set rectangle split with same height?

Tags: tikz-pgf, height

I want to have same height for the splitted rectangle's rows. Their height changes based on the character inside each section, for example `.` is much smaller than having larger characters like `f`.

my code:

```tex
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    chains,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes
}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        data/.style={
                draw,
                rectangle split,
                rectangle split parts=4,
                text centered,
                font=\scriptsize
            }
    ]
    \node [data,label=below:{test}] (n1) {
            GOOGLE
            \nodepart{second} IPFS
            \nodepart{third} ipfs
            \nodepart{fourth} .
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Here all the sections have different height, for example forth row is much smaller. Is it possible to make all rows same height?

Could be related to: [How to set rectangle split with the same size (width and height)？](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638146/how-to-set-rectangle-split-with-the-same-size-width-and-height)

Comment: You can add a \strut to the text in each row.  I wonder if there is an `every part/.style`?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651341/6880 .

Comment: Strangely, there seems to be no `every part/.style`. Additionally, it seems not to be possible to set `minimum height` to the node parts, at least not in vertical orientation: "When split vertically, the rectangle split will meet any minimum width requirements, but any minimum height will be ignored" (page 820, Ti*k*Z manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks using ` \strut` helped to format text in each row.

Comment: `nicematrix` and `tabularray` should be good for this kind of diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The straight-forward approach would be to apply `minimum height` to the nodes. But as the Ti*k*Z manual states (on page 820 of the [current version](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)):

> When split vertically, the rectangle split will meet any minimum width requirements, but any minimum height will be ignored.

However, as stated in the comments, you can add `\strut` to the contents of each of the nodes. You can use the following approach to do this automatically using `execute at begin node`:

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    chains,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric,
    shapes
}
\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    data/.style={
            draw,
            rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=4,
            text centered,
            font=\scriptsize,
            execute at begin node=\strut
        }
    ]
    \node [data,label=below:{test}] (n1) {
        GOOGLE
        \nodepart{second} IPFS
        \nodepart{third} ipfs
        \nodepart{fourth} .
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I use `inner ysep=1pt` to make height for all rows little bit smaller?

Comment: Sure, this should work fine.